# Permission Sets in APEX

Tags: apex, soql, package, permission-sets

I can easily query for a permission set by name:

```
PermissionSet permSet = [select id from PermissionSet where name=:name];
```

But it is possible to query for permission sets by package?

Answer (score 2):

There is a `NamespacePrefix` column that you can include in the `where` clause (assuming you know the namespace prefix for the package).

**PS**

A couple of ways to see the fields of an SObject are to run the below code in  the Developer Console -> Debug -> Open Execute Anonymous window:

```
SObjectType t = PermissionSet.SObjectType;
List<String> l = new List<String>(t.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
l.sort();
System.debug(String.join(l, ', '));
```

or in the Force.com IDE double-click on the "salesforce.schema" file located in the project root and then drill down on the SObject you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You would be able to get permission sets specific to package by below code.
Considering you have values in namespacePrefix and Name variable.

PermissionSet permSet = [SELECT Id,NamespacePrefix, name FROM PermissionSet WHERE NamespacePrefix=:namespacePrefix AND Name = :Name];

Hope this helps you.